# How to render variable components in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Can someone help me render react components with variable names? For example, I have a component that imports 3 other components and I want to loop through the array of components and render them. Very rough pseudocode:

```
import component1 from '...';
import component2 from '...';
import component3 from '...';

const component_list = ['component1', 'component2', 'component3']

renderComponents() {
    return this.component_list.map((component) {
      <div>
        <{component} />
      </div>
    });
}
```

Comment: I was going to say your already their expert for the curly braces.  Gj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the list of components with the components classes (rather than strings) and note that custom components [must be capitalised](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized):

```
import component1 from '...';
import component2 from '...';
import component3 from '...';

const component_list = [component1, component2, component3];

renderComponents() {
    return this.component_list.map((Component) => {
      <div>
        <Component />
      </div>
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import component1 from '...';
import component2 from '...';
import component3 from '...';

const component_list = [component1, component2, component3]

renderComponents() {
    return component_list.map((component) => {
      <div>
        <component />
      </div>
    });
}
```